# fmt:formatDate returns 12 hr format.How can i change it to 24 hr format

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${event.eventDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" var="parseDate" /> 
<fmt:formatDate value="${parseDate}" type="time" var="sTime" />
```

My aim is to convert the timestamp value to time and date.event.eventDate has value "2014-12-26 22:50:00

stime output is 10:50:00 PM. How can I conver it to 24 hr time?

Comment: Try the `formatDate` also with the pattern

Comment: @Regent 
hh gives an error as given below....
thats y i have changed it to HH.I think the error happens because of 24 hr time.
HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: In &lt;parseDate&gt;, value attribute can not be parsed: "2014-12-18 20:45:00.0"

Comment: @cy3er when i use format with ${event.eventDate} gives an error.Thats y i have first parsed it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

changed type="time" to pattern="HH:mm:ss" for fmt:formatDate ,  it gives desired 20:45:00

Comment: @demostene no its not that way. Your answer does't outputs according to my question. So i have provided the answer that i have founded out . Hope it may help someone. Happy to Help always.

Answer (score 3):

Using `HH` should give you the 24 hr format. You could also use `kk` - the only difference is that it is using the 1-24 interval.

Also "formatDate" tag must have the pattern="HH:mm:ss" inside.

Comment: i have tried it but nothing changes..still parse date gives same 12 hr output..
Thu Dec 18 20:45:00 EST 2014 2014-12-18
8:45:00 PM

Comment: @shalu inside <fmt:formatDate> could you add the same pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ?

Comment: Thank you.i have solved it. 
changed type="time" to pattern="HH:mm:ss" for fmt:formatDate , it gives ....20:45:00